# Handle static pages in Angular by fileReplacments

Tags: angular

I am looking the solution for below problem.

My app will be consists of two parts:

1. SPA APP - Angular App - standard configuration/schema,

`app/src/...index.html` -> from that place is bootstraping  component.

2. Folder with static html and several landing page

   ```
   Folder:
        LandingPage1/index.html (and another pages)
        LandingPage2/index.html (and another pages)
        LandingPage3/index.html (and another pages)
        index.html
   ```

The problem is:

From backend, from the 1st request I got information about LandingPage name - f.e. LandingPage1.
I would like bootstrap Angular app from

```
Folder:

LandingPage1/index.html (and another pages)
LandingPage2/index.html (and another pages)
LandingPage3/index.html (and another pages)
index.html <- here - <app-root>
```

And depend of request response have route access to that same name folder with LandingPage.

In React - we have special solution for it - and it is pretty easy:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

That we can do it that same in angular? Now I am trying:

-> put LandingPages folder to assets
-> and in angular.json handle it (index.html) by fileReplacments (but what with css?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use your own logic and the backend plus `Angular-router` to handle routes (Read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router))

After components and routes are created to render an HTML file in the template you could use `[innerHtml]`. Keep in mind the file extension wouldn't be printed in the URL as it is injected into the Angular template, so by default it would look like `example.com/LandingPage1` instead of `example.com/LandingPage1/index.html`

The best practise is to store the html files in /src/views folder

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
var template = require("./html1.html");

declare var require: {
(path: string): any;
<T>(path: string): T;
(paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
ensure: (paths: string[], callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => 
void) => void;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="html1">`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  html1:string = template;
}
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8s7x97?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

> (but what with css?)

After that you could import your global CSS here:

[image]

Comment: I added src/views path to assets in angular.json, but I can't build project:
```Cannot find module ../view/LandingPage1/index.html```

Comment: I updated my anwer with a working stackblitz, hope this works for you. @profiler